# How train neural network in OpenCV on histograms

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, neural-network

I want to train mlp in OpenCV to recognize if there is an specified object on an image.
The problem is as far as I know, constructors of Mat object (with wich mlp operates) can use just simple variables types. So I can't use Mat of Mat, vector or Mat of hists even despite the fact it consists of floats, I don't see the way to split the objects inside it, if I use the only one Mat object to collect all hists.
Sorry if question is stupid.
P.S. I need to use mlp concrete, because Haar cascade is used already and alternative way is neccessary to look of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mat trainingDataMat(600, 8, CV_32FC1, trainingData);

Mat labelsMat(600, 1, CV_32SC1, labels);

Ptr svm = SVM::create();

svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);

svm->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);

svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6));

svm->train(trainingDataMat, ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);